# v8 memory leaks in fork daemons

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, fork, v8

- v8 version is 6.3.292
- Centos6/7

I have such kind of architecture(my daemon has asynchronous working model):

1. I init v8 platform with one thread, which forks 3-4 children.
2. I init isolate for every child and master.
3. Master has no memory leaks, but children do.
4. At some time children go to 99% CPU and do nothing.

Even if I try to initialize platform for every master&child, I have the same issue

In v8's version 3.14 such model gave no memory leaks.

```
v8::Isolate* isolate;

struct Context {
    v8::Persistent<v8::Context> ctx;
};

void init_v8_platform() {
    v8::V8::InitializePlatform(v8::platform::CreateDefaultPlatform(1));
    v8::V8::Initialize();
    v8::V8::InitializeICU();
}

void init_v8_isolate() {
    v8::Isolate::CreateParams params;
    params.array_buffer_allocator = v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
    params.constraints.set_max_old_space_size(20);
    params.constraints.set_max_semi_space_size(20);
    params.constraints.set_max_executable_size(20);
    isolate = v8::Isolate::New(params);
}

void* init_v8_ctx() {
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

    v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);

    v8::Local<v8::Context> ctx = v8::Context::New(isolate, NULL, global);

    Context* v8_ctx = new Context;
    v8_ctx->ctx.Reset(isolate, ctx);

    return v8_ctx;
}

char* read_template(char* template_path, size_t* buff_size) {
    struct stat st;
    if (stat(template_path, &st)) {
        printf("failed to stat file");
        exit(0);
    }
    FILE *f = fopen(template_path, "rb");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("no file found");
        exit(0);
    }
    char* buff = (char*) malloc(st.st_size*sizeof(char));
    *buff_size = st.st_size;

    int res = 0;
    do {
        if (fread((void*) buff, *buff_size, 1, f) != 1) {
            break;
        }
        res = 1;
    } while(0);

    if (res == 0) {
        printf("failed to read file");
        exit(0);
    }

    return buff;
}

int expand_template(void* v8_ctx, char* buff) {
    //printf("%s", buff);
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

    v8::TryCatch tc(isolate);

    Context* ct = (Context*)v8_ctx;
    v8::Local<v8::Context> ctx = v8::Local<v8::Context>::New(isolate, ct->ctx);
    v8::Context::Scope context_scope(ctx);

    v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String> script = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, buff);
    if (script.IsEmpty()) {
        return 1;
    }

    v8::Local<v8::String> s = script.ToLocalChecked();
    //printf("%s\n", *buff);

    v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Script> scr = v8::Script::Compile(ctx, s);
    if (scr.IsEmpty()) {
        return 1;
    }

    v8::Local<v8::Script> sc = scr.ToLocalChecked();
    v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> res = sc->Run(ctx);
    if (res.IsEmpty()) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (tc.HasCaught()) {
     //   printf("%s:%s", "HasCaught exception");
    }

    return 0;
}

int expand_forever(void* v8_ctx, char* template_path) {
    size_t buff_size = 0;
    char* buff = read_template(template_path, &buff_size);

    int res;
    for (;;) {
        res = expand_template(v8_ctx, buff);
        if (res != 0) {
            printf("%s", "failed to expand template");
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", "success");
        }
    }

    free(buff);
}

void serve(int children, char* template_path) {
    if (children == 0) {
        init_v8_isolate();
        void* ctx = init_v8_ctx();
        expand_forever(ctx, template_path);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < children; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        switch (pid){
        case -1:
            printf("%s\n", "failed to fork");
            exit(0);
        case 0:
            printf("%s\n", "forking");
            init_v8_isolate();
            void* ctx = init_v8_ctx();
            expand_forever(ctx, template_path);
        }
    }
    for (;;) {}
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    init_v8_platform();
    char* template_path = "test.js";

    serve(5, template_path);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't spot a single `delete` statement in the code you posted. Where is `v8_ctx` supposed to be deallocated?

Comment: You should init context after forking.

Comment: I init context after forking, its done if I am in a fork.

Comment: I dont delete, everything runs in one context just like in https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/samples/process.cc

Comment: @AleksandrPetrukhin Try using a `std::unique_ptr<Context>` instead of `Context*`, pass that one around, and see if the leaking behavior pertains.

Comment: Calling `init_v8_platform();` is the first thing you do after entering `main`.

Comment: @VTT I do that as it's told in v8 samples.

Comment: @user0042 It's leaking anyway(

Comment: @VTT changing platform to global unique_ptr with check on not NULL on start didnt help

Comment: What makes you think this is a memory leak? Where exactly do the child processes get stuck? What's in your test.js file?